# Difference between MPEG-TS and RTP for .mp4 video streaming?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, mp4

So I am trying to stream a .mp4 video over ETHERNET using the ffmpeg tool. I have read a little about transport of .mp4 video and have learnt that there are two methods; mpeg-ts and RTP (both over UDP). I have been able to stream the .mp4 video through both methods in ffmpeg and haven't noticed any difference in quality or latency as such. What is the difference in concept and efficiency between the two protocols for transportation of video? Or am I mixing two different concepts? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, I vaguely remember that MPEG-TS isn't a standalone protocol, just an encapsulation format that is _used by_ RTP and other protocols.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please take the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to get your first badge

Comment: It’s two way of accomplishing the same thing. RTP probablly uses a very tiny bit less bandwidth. But effectively it doesn’t matter.

Comment: @grawity isn't RTP essentially a packetization protocol too? It runs on top of UDP.

Comment: @szatmary thanks for your comment, I will look into that. Is there any command in ffmpeg that can be used to confirm the bandwidth used?